# Com chamar um arquivo em Clojure?

Tags: programação-funcional, lisp, clojure

Olá, eu já pesquisei em diversos lugares, porém não encotrei a resposta que queria. Tenho a seguinte função no arquivo **inicio.clj**

```
(defn hello [request]
 (let [name (get-in request [:route-params :name])]
     {:status 200
       :body (str "Olá " name ".  Vamos as pergutas!")
       :headers {}}))
```

E gostaria de chamar essa função "hello" em outro aquivo chamado **core.clj**. Como eu coloco no cabeçalho de core.clj para que eu possa usar as funções disponiveis em "inicio.clj"? (seria algo com includ<> em C).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quiser carregar um módulo em LISP você pode usar `require` ou `load`.

A diferença entre eles é que o `require` é específico para carga de módulos escritos em LISP. Já o `load` pode ser usado com qualquer tipo de arquivo.

A função require testa se um módulo já está presente, usando uma comparação com distinção entre maiúsculas e minúsculas, se o módulo não estiver presente, solicita o carregamento do arquivo ou conjunto de arquivos apropriado. O argumento do nome do caminho, se presente, é um nome de caminho único ou uma lista de nomes de caminho cujos arquivos devem ser carregados em ordem, da esquerda para a direita. Se o argumento do nome do caminho é nulo ou não é fornecido, o sistema tentará determinar, de alguma maneira dependente do sistema, quais arquivos carregar. Isso normalmente envolverá algum registro central de nomes de módulos e as listas de arquivos associadas.

**Sintaxe:**

```
(require nome-do-módulo [caminho])
```

- *nome-do-módulo* é nome do módulo a ser carregado.
- [*caminho*] é um opcional que informa o caminho do arquivo.

---

A função load carrega o arquivo nomeado no ambiente Lisp. Supõe-se que um texto(arquivo de caractere) pode ser automaticamente distinguido de um arquivo de objeto(binário) por algum meio dependente de implementação apropriado, possivelmente pelo tipo de arquivo. Os padrões para nome do arquivo são obtidos da variável default-pathname-defaults. Se o nome do arquivo(após a mesclagem dos padrões) não especificar explicitamente um tipo, e os tipos de texto e objeto do arquivo estiverem disponíveis no sistema de arquivos, o carregamento deverá tentar selecionar o arquivo mais apropriado por alguns meios dependentes da implementação. .

**Sintaxe:**

```
(load filespec [verboso] [print] [if-does-not-exist] [external-format])
```

- *filespec* é uma stream ou o caminho para o arquivo.
- [*verboso*] valor lógico opcional indicado se o arquivo será carregado
  em modo verboso. True para modo verboso e false para silencioso.
- [*print*] valor lógico opcional indicado se o conteúdo do arquivo será
  ecoado da saída padrão(stdio). True para ecoar e false para não
  ecoar.
- [*if-does-not-exist*] valor lógico opcional indicado se a carga do
  arquivo deve gerar um asserção caso não exista. True para gerar
  asserção e False para não gerar asserção.
- [*external-format---an external*] formato designado ao arquivo. Também
  opcional.

---

Para mais informações sobre [require](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node119.html) e [load](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node217.html).

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu queria, muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro criei uma app para o exemplo `lein new app hello`

Em `src/hello/` criei o arquivo `inicio.clj`:

```
;;inicio.clj
(ns hello.inicio)

(defn hello [request]
 (let [name (get-in request [:route-params :name])]
     {:status 200
       :body (str "Olá " name ".  Vamos as pergutas!")
       :headers {}}))
```

E no `core.clj` chamo a funcão `hello` de `inicio.clj` com `(:require [hello.inicio :refer [hello]])`:

```
;; core.clj
(ns hello.core
  (:require [hello.inicio :refer [hello]]))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println (hello {:route-params {:name "World"}})))
```

Resultado do `lein run`:

```
{:status 200, :body Olá World.  Vamos as pergutas!, :headers {}}
```